# Intellij IDEA doesn't show warnings on scroll bar in a dark theme

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings

When the theme is light, I see warnings on the scroll bar as on the image:

http://prntscr.com/gi6w82

But if I set the theme to dark, I dont see any warnings on the scroll bar:

http://prntscr.com/gi6wrx

What should I change in settings to see warnings with dark theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your color scheme in `Editor > Color Scheme > General > Errors and Warnings`.

If you want the `Error stripe mark` in the gutter in the right hand side of your code editor to be visible in a dark theme then you'll probably want to choose a colour such as: `BC3F3C`

Here's a screenshot showing the relevant configuration:

[image]

The same approach can be followed to set the colour for the various other entries under `Errors and Warnings`. For example, you'll probably want to set the error stripe mark for the `Warning` node (which is the one shown/not shown in your screenshots) to `BE9117`.

Note: if you choose the built-in dark theme **Darcula** (by selecting `Scheme: Darcula` within `Editor > Color Scheme > General`) then visible colours are already configured for you.